# Laptop repeatedly shows BSOD, likely due to faulty wireless network adapter. What are my options?

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, bsod, acer-aspire

Apologies for the long post but I am trying to be thorough.

I have an Acer Aspire V15 Nitro (Model: Aspire VN7-591G) laptop that I bought on November 2015. It came with Windows 8, which I immediately upgraded to Windows 10 without facing any problems.

In late July, I installed Ubuntu GNOME as an additional OS for my uni classes. There weren't any problems then either.

Then in mid-August, I received the Windows 10.1 update, and a few weeks later my wifi adapter started working funny. Sometimes, like maybe once or twice a week, I would boot up Windows and find that there is no WiFi or Bluetooth at all in my laptop. Those options vanish as if they were never available on the machine to begin with. It didn't work if I rebooted it either. Then I'd start Ubuntu and usually that won't have WiFi either.

There were some solutions available online for that, the most popular being the one that required deleting a specific registry via command prompt. That didn't work for me as the said registry could not be found on my PC.

The problem would resolve itself when I booted the PC after several hours and after that it won't reoccur for days.

Over the last few days, however, I have been constantly receiving a BSOD on Windows with the stop code '0x000001d3'. This happens most frequently when I move my laptop, say, with one hand grabbing one of its corners. But it has also occurred almost just as regularly when it is placed stationary on a surface. The PC would then reboot, and sometimes, the no WiFi/Bluetooth thing would reoccur. When it doesn't, the blue screen would appear again after a few minutes or hours of usage.

Sometimes the error code would be replaced with 'kernel auto boost lock acquisition with raised irql'. A YouTube solution for that suggested updating the Intel Management Engine Interface driver, which I did, but then a few minutes later, the blue screen appeared again with the '0x000001d3' error.

I disabled the wireless network adapter for a couple of days, and found that the BSOD did not appear again at all. After re-enabling it, it took less than an hour for the BSOD to reappear. So the problem is almost definitely due to that. The drivers are updated and reinstalling the device did not fix it either.

My question is: will removing and refitting the wireless network adapter fix the issue?

Thanks, hope I didn't miss out anything.

My wireless network adapter is Qualcomm Atheros QCA61x4.

Comment: "will removing and refitting the wireless network adapter fix the issue?" Maybe? Probably not, but try it and see.  "how much would a company repair/replacement like this generally cost outside of warranty" this is not a valid question for Superuser.com.

Comment: Fair enough. I do realize my question was very narrow, but I didn't know where else to put it. Thanks tho.

Comment: Did you update the wireless adapter driver after going to Windows 10.1 from Windows 8?

Comment: @DrZoo: No. I did not explicitly update any drivers myself after upgrading to Windows 10. I checked for new updates of the wireless adapter driver through Device Manager as recently as a couple hours ago but it shows as updated.

Comment: "Then in mid-August, I received the Windows 10.1 update" - Please don't call this update 10.1, its not 10.1, its called Version 1607.  **Officially there is no such thing has Windows 10.1**

Comment: @Ramhound: I am sorry. I honestly believed that was the official name. Should do more research clearly.

Comment: Device manager is absolutely terrible at detecting updated drivers. It's essentially worthless in my point of view. Always go to the hardware manufactures website to look for updated drivers. Here are [your drivers](http://support.lenovo.com/us/en/downloads/ds105386). Give that a shot and let us know if it stops the BSOD's.

Comment: @DrZoo: the link you provided is for Lenovo. My laptop is Acer. Can I use that driver for my laptop? Because the supported models are listed as some Lenovo models. I checked out the Acer website but they don't have drivers for my wireless network adapter.

Comment: "Can I use that driver for my laptop?"  - Yes;  What you want is a Windows 10, Qualcomm Atheros QCA61x4.driver, which is what DrZoo provided a link to.  If the executable prevents you from installing the driver, extract the .inf. and manually point device manager to it.

Comment: Sorry I have a Lenovo sitting in front of me and didn't realize what I did. The driver itself should not be manufacture specific. The driver is for a QCA61x4 Windows 10 x64 so you should be fine.

Comment: Well I ran the .exe file and I believe the driver is now updated. If I remember correctly, the previous driver date was February 2016, and the new one is April 2016. I am going to use it for a day and see if the BSOD reappears. I'll post any update here. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Updating the driver seems to have fixed the problem in Ubuntu. Previously, the wireless would stop working after some time on it. But that doesn't happen anymore. Unfortunately, the BSOD still occurs on Windows, although the frequency of it seems to have reduced. I think this may be a problem with the hardware itself. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: UPDATE: The problem persists on Ubuntu as well. I didn't use it enough to notice it, but now I have. It now happens usually when I move the laptop.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issues and fixed it by installing the windows8.1 (x64) version of the driver (v 11.0.0.373) (i'm running windows 10 (x64) with the most recent version to date)

it can be found at acer support website :

https://global-download.acer.com/GDFiles/Driver/Wireless%20LAN/Wireless%20LAN_Atheros_11.0.0.373_W81x64_A.zip?acerid=635623279104910928&Step1=NOTEBOOK&Step2=ASPIRE&Step3=ASPIRE%20VN7-591G&OS=81P1&LC=fr&BC=ACER&SC=EMEA_13

step :
1 -  download the correct driver from previous link.
2 -  Remove current driver (wifi will be innactive)
3 -  Reboot
4 -  install driver v 11.0.0.373
5 -  Reboot again
6 - No more BSOD (so far)

If you have an Win10 Pro version, you can disabled any futher update to this specific device by following this guide :
https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/146562-prevent-windows-update-updating-specific-device-driver.html

sources that helped me :
https://forums.malwarebytes.com/topic/174990-bsod-on-acer-v-15-nitro/

Hope it helps